# Firebase Firestore - OR query

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

How to get data by multiple values of one field? For example, I have a database with posts and I want to query for all posts where blogId is 1 or 2, sorting by timestamp.

```
collection("posts").whereEqualTo("blogId", "1")
.whereEqualTo("blogId", 2).orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(50)
```

The code above is not working :(

How to achieve this?
Regards :)

Comment: This is now possible due to the Nov 7 update. Please update accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59039919/2057171

Comment: Aside from the below answers, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-or-queries-in-firestore-6f9bc895ff83) will help.

Answer (score 43):

[Firestore now supports "IN" queries](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/11/cloud-firestore-now-supports-in-queries.html) for this purpose.

The query would look like this:

```
database.collection("collectionName").where("fieldName", "in", ["fieldValue1", "fieldValue2"]);
```

You can have up to 10 values (fieldValueX) to check "IN" of.

---

The code OP desired would be as follows:

```
database.collection("posts").where("blogId", "in", ["1", "2"]);
```

Comment: What about multiple fields?

Comment: @IsraelObanijesu As far as I understand you'll have to use compound queries for that, but it would be worth checking the firebase docs to make sure. I don't work much with queries like this

Comment: Good answer although this is a very poor implementation on firebase's side
And with a tight limitation of 10 values...

Answer (score 20):

You could combine the Observables and return as one

```
orQuery(){

    const $one = this.afs.collection("posts", ref => ref.where("blogId","==","1")).valueChanges();
    const $two = this.afs.collection("posts", ref => ref.where("blogId","==","2")).valueChanges();

    return combineLatest($one,$two).pipe(
        map(([one, two]) => [...one, ...two])
    )
}

getOr(){
    this.orQuery().subscribe(data => console.log(data))
}
```

Comment: Note that final result might contain duplicates in this approach, depending on the query (in this exact scenario, there won't be duplicates sine same field is used for query with different values).

Comment: It may be hard if we use multi fields like your answer to paginate data.

Comment: really good clear answer - many thx - a shame this is the best approach and Google can't provide a better solution

Answer (score 8):

Firebase has listened to our requests and they have included `IN` query from `7 Nov, 2019`. It's a kind of `OR` query, where you can have upto `10 OR` filters.

For android:

```
collection("posts").whereIn("blogId", Arrays.asList("1", "2"))
.orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(50);
```

[Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any)

Comment: Should be the correct answer

Answer (score 6):

`OR` operator is not accepted in firebase firestore:

> Cloud Firestore provides limited support for logical OR queries. The in, and array-contains-any operators support a logical OR of up to 10 equality (==) or array-contains conditions on a single field. For other cases, create a separate query for each OR condition and merge the query results in your app.

[Queries in Cloud Firestore, Query limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations)

Normally using firebase syntax you can call two collections:

```
const res1 = async collection("posts", ref => ref.where('blogId', '==', 1).get();
const res2 = async collection("posts", ref => ref.where('blogId', '==', 2).get();
```

and you can merge the results before serving to the view.

But in this case where you have blogIds you can use this syntax:
`collection("posts").orderBy('blogId').startAt(1).endAt(2);`

e.d

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't find any documentation for the ability to OR together where conditions.  But you can rephrase your requirement on the `blogId` as follows:

```
WHERE blogId > 0 AND blogId < 3
```

Try this code:

```
collection("posts")
.where("blogId", ">", "0")
.where("blogId", "<", "3")
.orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
.limit(50)
```

Comment: Yeah, but my case is little more complicated. I have an app, where user can subscribe to some blogs. So I need to retrieve all latest posts for few ids (it can be 2,5 or more ids). The ids are autogenerated (for wordpress for example - 831cacax613das) or are from blogger (for blogspot blogs - 12320183127312307212). 
I'm currently using firebase database with elasticsearch, but I'm interested in migrating to Firestore.

Comment: Check here for how to work with collections: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/arrays

Comment: Hmm, I could store blogId with single element map and query for it like in example, but in that case each blogId will require individual index for it. Currently I have 300 blogs in my database, but what if I have few thousands? :D
Even if I will store it in map with integer value instead of boolean, I can query only with one field, so it's impossible to invoke this: .whereGreaterThan("blogIdMap.kqy04zya72zit5x7n9", 0)
                .whereGreaterThan("blogIdMap.kqy0n2dt2maqluvi3eu", 10)

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a problem.  Could you join to a table which has those IDs?

Comment: Nope, Currently I'm storing blogId in post entity as normal field (blogId = 123131). But, users have map of subscribed blogs (123131 = true). I'm thinking about merging query observables into one, but it's not good idea, because I want to get f.e. 10 latest posts. And I will loose pagination ability.

Comment: @Skye I gave you an upvote, which is as much as I can do.  Anyway for small ranges my answer might actually be viable, so I will leave it up.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Does this works? Because from what I read, when using  range comparison, you can use orderBy only on the key you applied comparision. In this case, it is "blogId" only. So orderBy on "timestamp" will not work. Can you please confirm if it's working?

Comment: @SandipSoni I can't test Firebase at the moment.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I didn't meant that :) I meant if you remember that was working for you when you used it with Firestore.

Comment: This doesn't work because the Range filter and orderBy on different fields. Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

Comment: Note, firebase does now support IN query which works like OR for this purpose. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59039919/2057171

Answer (score 4):

Firestore now supports [OR queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#or_queries) (in preview) that might be useful if you want to perform an OR operation on multiple fields.. You can use it from Firebase SDK [`v24.4.5`](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#firestore_v24-4-5).

```java
// Returns all documents with capital = true OR population > 1000000
Query query = collection.where(Filter.or(
        Filter.equalTo("capital", true),
        Filter.greaterThanOrEqualTo("population", 1000000)
));
```

Answer (score 3):

For Android users, please note that Firestore supports now [logical OR queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#or_queries). So now, you can perform OR queries on multiple fields. The option is available starting with Cloud Firestore version **24.4.5**.

In code, it will be as simple as:

```
val db = Firebase.firestore
val citiesRef = db.collection("cities")
val query = citiesRef.where(Filter.or(
        Filter.equalTo("capital", true),
        Filter.greaterThanOrEqualTo("population", 1000000)    
))
```

Which will return documents where the `capital` is set to `true` OR, documents where the population is greater than or equal to `1_000_000`.

Answer (score 2):

As of **March 2023**, Firestore supports native `or` queries: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#or_queries

An example they give is:

```js
const q = query(citiesRef,  
  or(where('capital', '==', true),
     where('population', '>=', 1000000)
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firestore has no `OR` queries. They way you'd do that is by running two queries and splicing them.

You could for example:

```js
const search = ( key, value ) =>  collection( 'users' ).where( key, '==', value ).get().then( doc => doc.data() )

Promise.all( [ search( 'name', 'John' ), search( 'name', 'Johnny' ) ] )
.then( ( [ one, two ] ) => one.concat( two ) )
.then( allResults => dothings() )
```

Answer (score 1):

For Android, I am using OR query like this.

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    values.add("Value 1");
    values.add("Value 2");
```

and then use the .whereIn query like this.

```
db.collection("collectionName")
            .whereIn("fieldName", values)   // where values is the list we created
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                      // Do your stuff

                    }

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
collection("posts").start("blogId", "1")
.end("blogId", 2).orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(50)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [De Morgaan's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) laws to rewrite an `AND` query as an `OR` query.

Comment: It would still be two quieres.

Comment: I may be mistaken but this applies to `XOR` not `OR` right?

Comment: You are mistaken 