# Firestore Query Android

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have orders collection in firestore which have status field (String), status field have those string (Pending, Cooking, Cooked, Shipped, Delivered), I want to query to get only those document which have status (Pending, Cooking, Cooked) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Firestore equivalent of a SQL `SELECT * FROM Collection WHERE status IN (Pending, Cooking, Cooked)`. The closest that Firestore has is to allow a range query, as [Tim shows here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46726925/209103). But that will only work if the values (`Pending, Cooking, Cooked`) are consecutive in the range. If they're not, you'll have to perform multiple queries.

Since these values sound like they might be steps in a process, you could consider prefixing them with a "step number": `1_Pending, 2_Cooking, 3_Cooked`. With those it becomes a lot easier to query a range of steps. Alternatively you could also *add* an additional `stepNumber` property, but you'd have to keep that in sync with the step name.

Comment: So it will be better if I use Interger value instead of strings?

Comment: If that makes it easier to ensure the values you want are in a range, it may help. But in that can you could also simply prefix the string with the same numbers (`1_Pending, 2_Cooking, 3_Cooked`) and filter on prefixes or add a field (e.g. step) and filter on that.

Comment: Thanks. prefix will be better :)