# How to filter list of id on firebase cloud firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have two collections. (`applyJobs` and `Jobs` and `users`). When users apply for a job, I store that record inside `applyJobs` collection. Like this:

```
applyId:****, 
jobId:*****,
userId:*****
```

Now, I want to show all apply for jobs by a user. 
First: Get logged user id, I store locally logged user id. So, I can get loggged user id.

Second: I filter Apply Jobs by that id. like this, `var ref = _db.collection('applyJobs').where('userId',isEqualTo: uid);`. I here I didn't call `users` collection to get uid. because I already store uid on locally. Is it best practice?

Third: I store result here `List<ApplyJobsModelClass>`. I want to get all jobs by a list of id. How do I filter it?

This is way I tried it. But this is not list of IDs. only one id.

```
streamApplyJob(List<String> jobId) {
   Collection('jobs').document(jobId);
}
```

And I tried this way too.

```
  Stream<List<JobModel>> streamApplyJob(List<String> jobId) {
     var ref = _db.collection('jobs').where('jobId',isEqualTo: jobId);
    return ref.snapshots().map((list) =>
        list.documents.map((doc) => JobModel.fromFirestore(doc)).toList());
  }
```

tried to get length, but result is `0`

```
db.streamApplyJob(jobIds).listen((v)=>{
  print(v.length)
});
```

**Full Code**

Database side

```
  ///Get a stream of apply jobs
  Stream<List<ApplyJobModel>> streamApplyJobs(String uid) {
    var ref = _db.collection('applyJobs').where('userId',isEqualTo: uid);

    return ref.snapshots().map((list) =>
        list.documents.map((doc) => ApplyJobModel.fromFirestore(doc)).toList());
  }

  ///Get a stream of a single document
  Stream<List<JobModel>> streamApplyJob(List<String> jobId) {
     var ref = _db.collection('jobs').where('jobId',isEqualTo: jobId);
    return ref.snapshots().map((list) =>
        list.documents.map((doc) => JobModel.fromFirestore(doc)).toList());
  }
```

calling

```
  List<String> jobIds = [];

  void getData() {
    db.streamApplyJobs(widget.uid).listen((listApplies) => {
          for (int i = 0; i < listApplies.length; i++)
            {jobIds.add(listApplies[i].jobId)},
        });
    db.streamApplyJob(jobIds).listen((v)=>{
      print(v.length)
    });
  }
```

**Solution(It's working now)- Is it best practice or are there other best way to do this?**

```
  Future<List<JobModel>> getJobs() async {
    await db.streamJobs(true).listen((jobs) {
      setState(() {
        jobModel = jobs;
      });
    });
    return jobModel;
  }

  Future getData() async {
    await getJobs();
    db.streamApplyJobs(widget.uid).listen((apply) => {
          for (int j = 0; j < jobModel.length; j++)
            {
              for (int i = 0; i < apply.length; i++)
                {
                  if (apply[i].jobId == jobModel[j].jobId)
                    {
                      jobModelNew.add(jobModel[j]),
                    }
                }
            }
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to get all jobs by a list of id. How do I filter it?

There currently is no way to pass in a list of IDs to a Firestore query and get documents matching all those IDs. See [Google Firestore - how to get document by multiple ids in one round trip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721517/google-firestore-how-to-get-document-by-multiple-ids-in-one-round-trip) (which talks about doing this with document IDs), and [Firebase Firestore - OR query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46726673/firebase-firestore-or-query) (which talks about filtering for multiple values on a single field).

Unless your use-case happens to match the workaround mentioned in that second answer, you'll have to perform a separate query for each value, and merge the results in your application code.

Comment: I did it like this: Please tell me, is it okay to best practice. First: I get all `jobs` collection data and store local variable. and I get all `applyJob` collection data and filter

Comment: I added my solution and please check and lemme know

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it is documented anywhere officially, but this is possible now!

```
.where(admin.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "in", [array, of, ids])
```

Found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52252264/10562805

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [this example](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore#-readme-tab-). It binds a CollectionReference to a List.

Let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: I added my solution..it's working now..please check and lemme know