# Filtering Firestore collection on DocumentReference snapshot "metadata"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

According to Firestore docs, collections can be filtered by the API client using methods like `.where()`, `.limit()` and `.limit_to_last()` : [docs](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/order-limit-data)

However, the `FilterField` argument in `.where()` supports queryable fields in the collection, which means you cannot use it to filter records on document attributes like `update_time` and `id`.

Unfortunately, my collection does not include last updated or document id fields but they are accessible in DocumentReference snapshot data (`collection().get()[i].id` and `collection().get()[i].update_time`).

What is the easiest way to filter the API for recently updated documents if your collection does not include a queryable field like `update_time`? Sorting and filtering the entire collection results in a timeout when using `stream()` to return all documents in the collection. Limit to last and limit do not seem to work since the collection also needs to be sorted on a queryable field.

I've tried various implementations of where, limit, and limit to last

Answer (score 0):

If you can't filter using a field, then you have to load all the documents and filter in memory.  There is no workaround for this.

You don't have to load all of the documents in one query.  You can [paginate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) the query results to load the documents in smaller batches.  But you still have to load them all in order to find matches.

> which means you cannot use it to filter records on document attributes like update_time and id.

Actually, you can filter using ID using the `firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId()` token (or whatever is the equivalent for your language.  See:

- [Query firestore database for document id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47876754/query-firestore-database-for-document-id)
- [How to filter list of id on firebase cloud firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58405909/how-to-filter-list-of-id-on-firebase-cloud-firestore)

And other things you might find using a web search for "firestore filter by document id".

Comment: Is it possible to add a new field for all documents in the collection based on the snapshot metadata?

Comment: No, you will have to write code to query for all of the documents and update them all individually with the fields you want them to have.